# Jquery Show/Hide in safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I created a simple navigation bar that shows and hides buttons using Jquery .show() and .hide(). It works properly when viewing in Firefox but when viewing in Safari it adds extra spaces into the navigation bar every time you hide/show the buttons.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/My4d4/

Comment: also has a problem in Chrome... the problem originates in the style rule `table-layout: fixed;` in `#navHolder`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

There seems to be a repainting "bug" in Webkit (the rendering engine used by Safari and Chrome), which causes `display: table-cell` elements to be repainted incorrectly. If the containing div (the one with `display: table` is hidden, and subsequently re-shown, the items will be painted correctly.

However, it seems that when a `display: table-cell` element is hidden and re-shown, its previous width is calculated back into the positioning of the cells as well as its current width, resulting in odd behavior.

I would suggest using percentile widths, `float: left` and the default display. If you want a table, use a table. If you want to avoid tables, avoid tables and do it right.

Please [see my working example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6BRJ/1/)